# Identifying some sort of flare near Earth

Tags: identify-this-object

Anyone know what this flare is in the top lefthand corner of the picture?

The image was [captured from the ISS live feed app for android 28/02/2019 at 18:38 BST](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/34518/identifying-some-sort-of-flare-near-earth#comment107933_34518)

[image]

Comment: For a reasonable expectation of getting an answer, information about where and when the picture was taken would be helpful.

Comment: it was captured from the iss live feed app for android 28/02/2019 at 18:38 bst

Comment: I can't see a flare in that image at all. Can you provide links, and maybe the frames immediately before and after

Comment: Is the camera inside or outside of the ISS?

Comment: Thank you I don't know where the camera is situated sorry also this is the only image I have,I captured it when I saw it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ISS live feed uses the cameras of the [HDEV experiment](https://eol.jsc.nasa.gov/ESRS/HDEV/).  This is a group of four cameras in a pressurized housing attached to the outside of the ISS.

[image]

The picture is from the forward-facing camera.  What you're seeing in the top-left corner of the image image are a dust filament on the housing (red circle), what appears to be sunlight reflecting off a surface defect of the housing (green), and the edge of the housing itself (blue).  The visibility varies with sun angle and brightness; they're not visible as I write this, but could be clearly seen shortly after the ISS came out of Earth's shadow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mark,It's amazing what reflected light can do

Comment: Cool answer! I've just asked [How is the atmosphere in the pressurized housing of ISS' HDEV cameras managed? Outgassing addressed?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34531/12102)